# Why does stdout decoding fail when adding carriage return?

Tags: java, utf-8, special-characters, decoding

The following java code does exactly what is expected:

```
1      String s = "♪♬♪♪♬♪♪♬♪♪♬♪♪♬♪♪♬♪";
2      for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++)
3      {
4         System.out.print(s.substring(i,i+1));
5         //System.out.print("\r");
6         Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
7      }
```

But when I try to add carriage return by commenting in line 5 it goes printing ?s.
Why is it and how will I fix it?

(I also tried with "\u240d" for carriage return - same thing).

EDIT: The output goes to a bash on Mac OS X.

Comment: Do you want those notes output underneath each other or to overwrite in-place at the beginning of a line?

Comment: would System.out.println not work?

Comment: Only if he wants to print *down*.

Comment: should we be assuming he wants to display one character at a time?

Comment: May be `\u000d` works better? `System.out.print('\u000d');` or `System.out.print("\u000d");`

Comment: @Carl: Yes they should overwrite each other and @aforloney: Carl's right, that's why println won't work.

Comment: Whoa, U+240D is already *named* "SYMBOL for carriage-return". I woudldn't have high hopes for that to work :-). VonC: that would be like you would be including a literal CR in the rouce. Last time I looked, those weren't valid in string or character literals.

Comment: @Carl and @Johannes: using \u240d (or \u000d) works good when parsed by reading in from properties file (System.out.print(props.get("UTF8240D"))) and for "normal character", e.g. replacing notes by "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP", which also works with "\r".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't know that your source file is UTF-8.

If you compile with

```
javac -encoding utf8 MyClass.java
```

and run with

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf8 MyClass
```

it will work.

(Does anyone know why UTF-8 isn't the default?)

Comment: Thank's also to the other answers from dtsazza and sascha. Even though  they were (mostly) right and made it possible to program a workaround, Jason gets the point for a simple solution without code changes.

Answer (score 4):

please also print s.length(), i bet it is more than 18.
the java string representation is utf-16, String.substring just extracts the char values.
the musical notes start at 0x1d000 - they don´t fit in a single char.
to extract complete codepoints/glyphs from a string use somthing like
[icu project - UCharacterIterator](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/UCharacterIterator.html)

ps: i don´t know if your terminal session can display those chars at all

Comment: Assuming the characters pasted into Firefox are the same in the app, they are U+266A and U+266C, both in the basic multilingual plane.

Answer (score 3):

I expect it is due to how your terminal is interpreting the output.

As has been pointed out above, all of the note glyphs are multibyte characters.  Additionally, Java `char`s are just 16 bits wide, so a single `char` cannot reliably represent a single Unicode character on its own - and subsequently the `String.substring` method isn't wholly multibyte friendly.

Thus what is likely happening is that on each iteration through the loop, Java prints out **half a character**, as it were.  When the first byte of a pair is printed out, the terminal realises it's the first half of a multibyte character and doesn't display it.  When the next byte is printed, the terminal sees the full character corresponding to the note and displays it.

What happens when you uncomment the `println("\r")`, is that you're inserting a newline *in the middle of* the two halves of each character.  Thus the terminal never gets the byte sequence e.g. 0x26, 0x6C representing [the note](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/266c/index.htm) but instead gets 0x26, 0x10, 0x6C, 0x10 so the note is not rendered.

Comment: So it is.  I guess I just remembered it was narrower than `int`, would hold an ASCII character but not many exotic Unicode characters, and then just failed to think/check.  Thanks for the somewhat embarassing correction!